# MySQL table. Should I use a cross-reference table?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I am presenting data output from MySQL on my website based on what city they belong to. So two of my tables are called `login_users` and `city_selection`. All tables has a column called `city_id`.

When a user signs in to my website, I ask the database what city_id is set, and then create a `$_SESSION['city_id']`

Then I am able to write my MySQL-querys with a `WHERE`-clause to the `$_SESSION['city_id']`.

For example: `SELECT firstname, lastname, city_name FROM students JOIN city_selection ON city_selection.city_id = students.city_id WHERE city_selection.city_id = '{$_SESSION['city_id']}'`

This works but now I need some users to display one or more regions of cities. My first thought was to create a new table called `region_selection` and add a Foreign Key from the table `city_selection` table to this. But how would I handle the scenario where a signed in user should be presented with data output from one or more regions? Should I create some kind of cross-reference table?

This is my first ever PHP - MySQL website so bear with me!

Answer (score 0):

If each city belongs to only one region, you could create your `region_selection` table with columns `region_id | region_name`. You then add a `region_id` column to your `city_selection` table, which defines the region to which a city belongs.

You could then execute a query like this to fetch students belonging to a certain region:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, city_name FROM students 
JOIN city_selection ON city_selection.city_id = students.city_id
JOIN region_selection ON region_selection.region_id = city_selection.region_id
WHERE region_selection.region_name = YOUR_REGION_NAME
```

---

If a user belongs to multiple regions, you could do the following: create table `region_selection` as shown above. Then create a table `student_regions` with columns `student_id | region_id` to make a link between a student and region.

The query then looks as follows:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, city_name FROM students 
JOIN student_regions ON student_regions.student_id = students.student_id
JOIN region_selection ON region_selection.region_id = student_regions.region_id
WHERE region_selection.region_name = YOUR_REGION_NAME
```

Comment: Yes that works. But how should I handle the scenario where a user "belongs" to multiple regions?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include your suggestion. Hope this is what you mean.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder however if there is possible using a cross reference table to link first a login_user to one or more regions, then the region will be linked to cities. Otherwise I need to create a student_region, customer_region, course_region etc etc wich isn't really a pretty structure.